# Copying formulas to a row When value is added

Tags: google-sheets

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KX0OWz0GNQZNGOcqF0enYgtEeb24ZlTlYhNdL_caidE/edit?usp=sharing)

HI!

I'm trying to make in "summary" sheet, that when I have a new value in column A it will paste dinamically the cells from the row before.
Any suggestions?

I have tried with ARRAYFORUMLA and INDIRECT with no success. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this in `Cell_B5` of the **summary** tab. Make sure to clear the range `B5:M` of any existing data/formulas so as for this formula to expand freely downwards+right_side*

```js
=map(A5:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(Σ,bycol(B4:M4,lambda(Λ,index(sumifs(AMOUNTS!D5:D,eomonth(AMOUNTS!C5:C,),eomonth(date(B1,month(Λ&1),1),),AMOUNTS!E5:E,Σ))))))
```

- *the formula takes `date` directly from `Column_C` of `AMOUNTS` tab*

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rockinfreakshow, it is working and i learned alot from your answer.
Can you explain how in the formula, you could still use the lambda name **Λ** In the `eomonth(date(B1,month(Λ&1),1)`? From what i understand the formula expression of the LAMBDA funcion isn't done so how can you cannot call it in the same expression?

Comment: To put it simply I am using your own sumifs() version & then adding map/lambda(with identifier *Σ*) to dynamically process each row (A5:A) and within it using bycol/lambda(with identifier Λ) to process the 12 months as a sub-loop. For example in first instance Income-A will be processed by map & 12 months will be processed by bycol; then map moves to next row (Income-B) & again 12 months processed by bycol & so on...